# Create A Search In A Section Of An Application With PhoneGap

Tags: database, search, cordova

I wanted to ask, how to create a search page in dreamweaver using PhoneGap.
Basically I have about 3000 addresses and I wanted to create a database that contained them and then connect it to the search page PhoneGap.
How can I do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple moving parts here, for which you need to decide your strategy.

Here's an [article and sourcecode](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/) for something very similiar to what you are trying to achieve.

Hope this helps get you started!